# Print Multiple Telerik Reports?

Tags: c#, printing, report, telerik-reporting

I currently have an ASP.Net/C# system which allows the User to Dynamically Create/Export (PDF) Telerik Reports for Employees in the database. The User is given the choice to Select from a list of Employee's to Export, or to Export them all.

The Telerik Report Viewer currently has a designated "Print" button, but I would like to give the Users the ability to Print Multiple Reports when Selected, or when the "Print All Reports" button is clicked.

Is there a way to proggramatically Print Multiple Dynamic Telerik Reports? (and give a Print Preview if possible?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the double-post, but I ended up solving this simple question on my own.

Using the Methods I had already written for the PDF export of the Reports, I looped through and added each Report to a ["ReportBook"](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-general-explanation#report-book). I then displayed the ReportBook in the ReportViewer I already had on my page.

This gave me the "Print Preview" aspect I was looking for, and the ability to Print Multiple Reports.

Thought I'd share for future reference

Best Regards